# Inner flexbox and its behavior with overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

First thing: I'm not a frontend programmer, but sometimes the only way is become one.

So I was thinking about behavior of flex or flexbox. Probably the way I use it is bad, if so, please let me know. Thanks.

## To the problem:

I tried to write basic layout using flexbox, but I found a problem.
Honestly I don't know if it is a bug or my expectations are too high, but I expect same behavior from these cases below.

https://jsfiddle.net/bargl_vojtech/upvb1Lgk/7/
https://jsfiddle.net/bargl_vojtech/h7eokuua/1/
https://jsfiddle.net/bargl_vojtech/q0kegr8o/1/

They are similar, but if you look closer, you can see change in `main` and `#inside-main` in css and `#wrapper` in html

### Simple info:

- `main` - part of view
- `#main-header` - header for content (example: fixed title)
- `#main-content` - scrollbox
- `#inside-main` - endless content

I expect second case to be just like first case in behavior, can someone tell me why it is not same?

Thanks for reply.

> My expectation: `main` has `flex: 1`, so it should be resize to rest of parent size, but somehow `#inside-main` tells `#main-content` to resize itself (because it expected in most cases... bigger inner div should resize smaller parent div to same size), and because `#main-content` is now bigger than its parent it resize him, and so on, but should not this be ignored by `overflow: hidden/scroll`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex items, by default, cannot shrink below the size of their content. That's why your content element is overflowing the container.

The initial setting on flex items is `min-height: auto` (in column container) and `min-width: auto` (in row container).

To override these defaults use `min-height: 0`, `min-width: 0`, or `overflow` with any value except `visible`.

Add this to your code:

```
main {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto; /* NEW */
}
```

For a complete explanation see these posts:

- [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)
- [min-width rendering differently in flex-direction: row and flex-direction: column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407619/min-width-rendering-differently-in-flex-direction-row-and-flex-direction-colum)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about that shrink feature, but it solved my problem